# adjustPan not working with FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS

Tags: android, statusbar, adjustpan

My Requirement is a full transparent status bar with change color of the status bar in same `activity` dynamically.

For that, I added `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);`

and in style.xml

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
```

So It's working fine but I need to adjust screen when soft keypad opens. 
So I tried `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` but screen not resized or scrolled. Anyone can help me on same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make transparent and  change color dynamically like this dont set flag `FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS` then check the screen when keypad is opened.

```
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources()
                    .getColor(R.color.themeToolbarColor));
        }
```

Comment: API level 21 required.

Comment: what about navigation color, navigation will not be transparent as it been done by FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS