# Window soft input modes not working with WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS

Tags: android, android-layout, input, android-softkeyboard

I've a customised status bar with gradient effect. I've achieved it using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36907237/how-to-apply-gradient-to-status-bar-in-android) solution. The main factor was `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS` flag. Have a look on the code...

```
public class ForgotPasswordActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Runnable {

    private AppBarLayout appBarLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_forgot_password);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
        params.height += getStatusBarHeight();
        toolbar.setLayoutParams(params);
        toolbar.setPadding(0, getStatusBarHeight(), 0, 0);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Default settings of the action bar
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            //actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp);
            //actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            //actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setTitle(0);
        }

        // Adding offset listener to block app bar sliding on touch
        appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar_layout);
        appBarLayout.post(this);          
    }

    public int getStatusBarHeight() {
        int result = 0;
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
        AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = (AppBarLayout.Behavior) params.getBehavior();
        if (behavior != null) {
            behavior.setDragCallback(new AppBarLayout.Behavior.DragCallback() {
                @Override
                public boolean canDrag(@NonNull AppBarLayout appBarLayout) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, soft input keyboard is covering the EditText as following...

[image: Screenshots]

Even I've also tried following links but nothing's happening...

- [adjustPan not working with FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39269543/adjustpan-not-working-with-flag-layout-no-limits)
- [adjustPan not preventing keyboard from covering EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558810/adjustpan-not-preventing-keyboard-from-covering-edittext)

I've to do it anyhow, because entire theme depends on this approach. So is there any way to adjust layout according to keyboard or achieve gradient in status bar without FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS?

Comment: For future references, this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33370845) applies for `FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS` as well.

Comment: Hello, did you figure it out?

Comment: Hello, did you figure it out?

Comment: Yeah I did it.. Do you want to see?

Comment: Hi Sourabh S Nath & Denny, I've fixed it using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140039/how-to-set-status-bar-background-as-gradient-color-or-a-drawable-in-android/43405486#43405486 approach, But there's a person @Bhargav Rao , who deleted my answer.

Comment: For future readers, the deleted answer mentioned by Khan pointed to this answer to a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140039/how-to-set-status-bar-background-as-gradient-color-or-a-drawable-in-android/43405486#43405486