# KeyboardDidShow/Hide events are not working on Android with adjustResize setting

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to capture events on Keyboard Show/Hide events on Android with `React Native`. I got stuck at a dead-end.

Here is my manifest setting:

```
<activity
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And here is my RN Component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    View,Keyboard
} from 'react-native';

export default class KeyboardAwareComponent extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidShow",()=>{
            console.log("Show event");
        })
    }

    render() {
        return <View />
    }
}
```

Thank you so much in Advance :)

Comment: Same thing for me. I have now realized that these lines are the issue:
`Window w = getWindow(); 
      w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);`
inside of `onCreate` of `MainActivity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some events straight from the docs.

keyboardWillShow

keyboardDidShow

keyboardWillHide

keyboardDidHide

keyboardWillChangeFrame

keyboardDidChangeFrame

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Keyboard, TextInput } from 'react-native';

class Example extends Component {
  componentWillMount () {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardDidShow);
    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._keyboardDidHide);
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
  }

  _keyboardDidShow () {
    alert('Keyboard Shown');
  }

  _keyboardDidHide () {
    alert('Keyboard Hidden');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        onSubmitEditing={Keyboard.dismiss}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I know about those events... But none of them are working on Android.

Answer (score 0):

TL/DR:

Make sure you're not using a view that's surrounded by a `ScrollView`

I've found for the `Keyboard` events to work, the correct visible part of the screen must be calculated on Android, and that doesn't work well when the view uses a ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the issue is I was using `FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS` which does not work with `adjustPan` or `adjustResize`

Inside of `MainActivity` I replaced this

```
      Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
      w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

with this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Window w = getWindow();
        w.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        w.setNavigationBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        w.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

for a similar behaviour.

Here is a few link relating the issue/solution:
[adjustPan not working with FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39269543/adjustpan-not-working-with-flag-layout-no-limits).
https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context/issues/8
https://unicorn-utterances.com/posts/draw-under-navbar-using-react-native/